# FFmpeg Filter Loop freezing when using delay or fade on overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working on a project where I've to do a batch. What i would want its make an animation all long of movie: this animation is mostly in two parts :
-1st part   Animated apparition of a picture  (0-5s)
-2nd part   Loop picture animation  (5s-end)

Separately these filters works but i cant make it working together, specifically for the loop filter starting after 5s

with fade :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 15 -i "cover.jpg" -i "input.mp3" -i "part1.avi" -i "part2.avi" -filter_complex "[3:v]loop=-1:500:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB [B];[B]fade=in:st=0:d=5:alpha=1 [part2];[0:v][2:v] overlay=enable='lte(t,5)': [part1];[part1][part2]overlay=x=0:y=0 [outx]" -map "[outx]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -crf 25 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -ar 48000 -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mp4
```

with delay :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 15 -i "cover.jpg" -i "input.mp3" -i "part1.avi" -i "part2.avi" -filter_complex "[3:v]loop=-1:500:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB [B];[B]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB [part2];[0:v][2:v] overlay=enable='lte(t,5)': [part1];[part1][part2]overlay=x=0:y=0 [outx]" -map "[outx]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 "output.mp4
```

Both overlay output are freezing at 25s so not looping as i would want.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english

PS: I'm on windows ffmpeg version N-93214-g7e4d3dbe18 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212

Comment: FFmpeg version is mandatory. For example loop filters were switched to activate API relatively very recently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using latest one on windows : ffmpeg version N-93214-g7e4d3dbe18 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212